# Объясните как достать данные из внутреннего массива JSON

Tags: java, android, json

Вот ссылка на json http://www.mocky.io/v2/58c8523127000052192bb2aa

вот мой код

```
String finalJson = response.body().string();
Log.d(TAG_LOG, "AllResponse = " + finalJson);

try {
    JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
    JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("orders");


    for (int i = 0; i <= parentArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);



                        }`
```

как получить вот эти 2 аргумента из внутреннего  массива 

`{"orders":[
  {
    "deliverytype": [
      "walk",
      "car"
    ],
  },
  {
    "deliverytype": [
      "walk",
      "car"
    ],
  }
]}`

Comment: А почему не пользуетесь Gson, если даже в тэгах его указали?

Comment: @EgorD я чуть изменил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("orders");


            for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONArray childArray = parentArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("deliverytype");
                for (int j = 0; j < childArray.length(); j++) {
                    System.out.println(childArray.getString(j));
                }
            }
```